# Designing a pin connection

Tags: structural-engineering, design, steel, connections

I am designing a pipe strut connected to a UB waler using a 100mm diameter pin through a series of 8 interlocking plates. Each plate is about 40mm thick. To be able to weld the plates to the waler and strut end, I need to leave sufficient space between consecutive plates.

Assuming the plates are 300mm wide and long, what should be the minimum gap between the plates to allow butt welding?

Should there be a maximum gap between each pair of plates if the pin can resist the bending moment induced by the bigger lever arm?